# Hook for replacing taxonomy term updating with my own function

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 4.1 ver.

Detected the following bug: Unable to update taxonomy terms with same slugs & names.

In post Category I create term 'foo'.
Then in post Tags I also create term 'foo'.
After that I try to edit Tag 'foo' (for example it's name) and save it. Wordpress outputs a message: 'Item not updated'. So I can't update the Tag term 'foo'.

So I'd like to know is there any hook to replace taxonomy term updating with my own function? 
I mean this for edit taxonomy admin menu page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the 'wp_terms' table? By what name are the category and the tag saved there?

Comment: Both "names" and "slugs" are saved with same names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per wp-includes/taxonomy.php. The edit related action for a term is:

```
do_action( "edited_term", $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
```

You can use this hook in your own function and update the term you want to update using its $term_id.

Answer (score 0):

```html
add_action( 'edited_service_category', 'service_category_term_slug_edit_success', 10, 2 );   // use your taxonomy instead of service_category so action will be edited_{custom_taxonomy}

/**
 * Custom redirect on taxonomy term update, keeps users on the term page for additional updates
 *
 * @param $term_id
 * @param $tt_id
 */
function service_category_term_slug_edit_success( $term_id, $tt_id ) {

    // Get the taxonomy slug.
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    $tax_slug = $term->taxonomy;
    
    // Setup the redirect URL.
    $tax_param = '&taxonomy=' . $tax_slug;
    $term_param = '&tag_ID=' . $term_id;
    $notice_param = '&notice=success';
    $redirect_url = admin_url( 'edit-tags.php?action=edit' . $tax_param . $term_param . $notice_param );
    
    if ( ( $_REQUEST['wpseo_focuskw'] )!="" ) {
        update_term_meta($term_id, 'focus_keyphrase_sync', $_REQUEST['wpseo_focuskw']);
    }

    // Redirect with new query strings.
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;

}
```